# Prevent hover function while moving on its child elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new in javascript. I've no technical skills in scripting.
Here I'm trying to write dropdown function with the help of javascript. I reached about 80%. My issue is, when hovering on the invisible/hide UL element, that ul is populated/ visible. For the sliding animation I used CSS transition. Please help me to finish my task 100%. [Here is my current working demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/naveen008/n1at667w/2/). Please move the mouse below about us(not hover it). I'm asking about that issue.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".menu-trigger").css({"display": "none"});
  $(".main-nav li").bind('mouseenter mouseleave', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("v-hover");
  });
});
```

```css
.navigation {
  background-color: #262626;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 30px;
  min-height: 36px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.navigation .menu-trigger {
  background-color: #ff8919;
  height: 42px;
  left: 0;
  padding: 7px 6px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 40px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.navigation .menu-trigger span {
  background-color: #262626;
  display: block;
  height: 3px;
  width: 22px;
}

.navigation .menu-trigger span + span {
  margin-top: 3px;
}

.main-nav {
  background-color: #262626;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1070px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  width: 100%;
}

.main-nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.main-nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
}

.main-nav a {
  background-color: #262626;
  border-bottom: #1e1e1e solid 1px;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 10px 22px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

.main-nav a:hover {
  background-color: #5a5a5a;
}

.main-nav li ul {
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 42px;
  width: 240px;
  transition: all ease 0.2s;
  -o-transition: all ease 0.2s;
  -webkit-transition: all ease 0.2s;
  transform: translateY(-20px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-20px);
  -o-transform: translateY(-20px);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-20px);
}

.main-nav li.v-hover ul {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0);
  -ms-transform: translateY(0);
  -o-transform: translateY(0);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
}

.main-nav li li {
  display: block;
  float: none;
}
```

```html
<section class="navigation" role="navigation">
  <button class="menu-trigger">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </button>
  <nav class="main-nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">home</a></li>
      <li><a href="">about us</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">Comapny</a></li>
          <li><a href="">mission</a></li>
          <li><a href="">vision</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">services</a></li>
      <li><a href="">gallery</a></li>
      <li><a href="">blog</a></li>
      <li><a href="">contact us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav><!-- End of .main-nav -->
</section><!-- End of .navigation -->
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this

```
$(".menu-trigger").css({"display", "none"});
```

Instead of

```
$(".menu-trigger").css({"display": "none"});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/iamraviteja/n1at667w/3/)

Comment: hi @Hazard, my doubt is not about Menu Trigger Function. Please leave that section. I've doubt in "main-nav" dropdown section

Comment: My problem is when hover below the ABOUT US menu(not hover it), its child ul is displaying. I can prevent this through css proerty. Now for the sub ul I used opacity and transform property. If these css remove and apply display none & block, there is no such issue. But I want a smooth sliding both horizontally and vertically. And one thing is I want javascript function for this dropdown menu. Not css

Answer (score 0):

Instead of binding the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events to the element, you can use jquery's `hover` function. Please find below a simple example for this,

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.main_nav li ul').hide().removeClass('fallback');
  $('.main_nav li').hover(
   function () {
    $('ul', this).stop().slideDown(100);
   },
   function () {
    $('ul', this).stop().slideUp(100);
   }
  );
});
```

```css
.main_nav {background:#FFF;float:left;}
.main_nav ul {text-align:center;}
.main_nav ul li {float:left;display:inline;}
.main_nav ul li:hover {background:#E6E6E6;}
.main_nav ul li a {display:block;padding:15px 25px;color:#444;}
.main_nav ul li ul {position:absolute;width:110px;background:#FFF;}
.main_nav ul li ul li {width:110px;}
.main_nav ul li ul li a {display:block;padding:15px 10px;color:#444;}
.main_nav ul li ul li:hover a {background:#F7F7F7;}
.main_nav ul li ul.fallback {display:none;}
.main_nav ul li:hover ul.fallback {display:block;}
```

```html
<section class="main_nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Tab 2</a>
      <ul class="fallback">
        <li><a href="#">Sub-Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-Tab 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-Tab 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Tab 3</a>
      <ul class="fallback">
        <li><a href="#">Sub-Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-Tab 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-Tab 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-Tab 4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Tab 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Tab 5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Tab 6</a></li>
  </ul>
</section>
```